# Translate between ibrav and space_group Quantum Espresso inputs

Tags: quantum-espresso

I am attempting to utilise the `space_group` option for potential performance speed-up. In this I have two Q.E. files which I hope would give equivalent results; however, the final energies differ. In the first file I use `ibrav = 0`:

```
&CONTROL
    calculation = 'scf'
    outdir = '/tmp/'
    prefix = 'graphene'
    pseudo_dir = 'pbe'
    restart_mode='from_scratch'
/
&SYSTEM
    ibrav = 0
    nat = 2, ntyp = 1,
    ecutwfc = 40.0 ,
    ecutrho = 400.0 ,
    occupations = 'smearing', degauss = 0.0001, smearing = 'marzari-vanderbilt'
/
&ELECTRONS
    conv_thr = 1.0d-10,
    mixing_beta = 0.3,
/
ATOMIC_SPECIES
C 12.01 C.upf
CELL_PARAMETERS angstrom
   2.465669985   0.000000000   0.000000000
  -1.232834994   2.135332846   0.000000000
   0.000000000   0.000000000   20.00000010
ATOMIC_POSITIONS crystal
C 0.000000000 0.000000000 0.250000000
C 0.333333333 0.666666667 0.250000000
K_POINTS automatic
12 12 1 0 0 0
```

In the second I use `space_group = 10`.

```
&CONTROL
    calculation = 'scf'
    outdir = '/tmp/'
    prefix = 'graphene'
    pseudo_dir = 'pbe'
    restart_mode='from_scratch'
/
&SYSTEM
    space_group = 10
    A = 2.465669985
    B = 2.465669985
    C = 20.00000010
    nat = 2, ntyp = 1,
    ecutwfc = 40.0 ,
    ecutrho = 400.0 ,
    occupations = 'smearing', degauss = 0.0001, smearing = 'marzari-vanderbilt'
/
&ELECTRONS
    conv_thr = 1.0d-10,
    mixing_beta = 0.3,
/
ATOMIC_SPECIES
C 12.01 C.upf
ATOMIC_POSITIONS crystal_sg
C 0.000000000 0.000000000 0.250000000
C 0.333333333 0.666666667 0.250000000
K_POINTS automatic
12 12 1 0 0 0
```

Why do I get different results?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You would get different energies because these two input files correspond to two different structures. This can be confirmed by inspecting these files using any crystal structure visualizer. Following pictures are from BURAI but XCrySDen can also be used to directly open Quantum ESPRESSO input files using the command:

```
xcrysden --pwi your_input_file.in
```

The first structure (with `CELL_PARAMETERS`):
[image]

The second structure (with `space_group`):
[image]

Comment: Thank you. Do you know how I can correctly translate between the two ways of inputting the crystal structure?

Comment: @Wychh your edit 3 hours ago attempted to add a new question to your question post. Please ask it in a new post.